# First time mass-emailing using Sendgrid with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

I am running a rails app on heroku and would like to send an email to 160 users. This is the first time I am doing this so I would to very whether the method below will lead to a successful outcome.

Sendgrid is all sent up and I have a controller setup that executes the following:

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |u|
  Email.send_email(p).deliver
end
```

I am assuming that since the number of recipients is relatively low I would be able to get by without using delayed_job or some other background processing.

Comment: move it to background. Heroku got 30s timout for requests and 160 emails is no a small amount. I had timeouts on heroku even with 2 emails.

Comment: @Eru Do you happen to know if you can still run delayed_job for free on heroku without scaling up?

Comment: you can. You can look into resque and resque_scheduler too

Comment: hmm, it seems that you need to scale to worker=1 which is 35 USD, am I wrong?

Comment: actually yes. I've just checked.

Comment: delayed_job requires:   $ heroku ps:scale worker=1    This costs money. Where did you check it, please?

Comment: I meant that it costs money. Sorry for misread question :)

Comment: @Eru you can start a worker from the command line on a live site. Why? Not sure. The docs say you have to scale to one worker...

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid actually makes it easy to send out emails without having to use a background worker.  You can do it using the X-SMTPAPI header and setting an array of email addresses in the `to` field.  For example:

```
X-SMTPAPI: {
  to: ["john.doe@example.com", "jackson@example.com", "freddy@example.com"]
}
```

In this example, each of these three emails will **receive a separate copy of the email**.  No background workers, no complexity.

---

There's a gem called `sendgrid` that does a good job of adding some useful helpers to action mailer.  Have a look at the "multiple recipients" section of the README

https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you invest the time into some background processing, as this could potentially be a hit or miss, all depending on the emailing service.